# Why does nothing occur when I try to rewrite the pointer to Direct3D device's `EndScene` function?

Tags: c++, directx, hook

I try to hook a DirectX 9 application to grab screenshots from it. That is what I do:

1. I inject my DLL with `CreateRemoteThread` and `LoadLibraryW` address
   passed as argument. I assume that the target application is already
   running at this moment.
2. Inside DLL's `DllMain` I `CreateThread` where I create a temporary
   Direct3D device to grab it's VMT:

   ```
   auto pID3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
   D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS pp = { };
   IDirect3DDevice9 *pID3DDevice = NULL;
   auto hr = pID3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_NULLREF, NULL,
       D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &pp, &pID3DDevice);
   auto pID3DDevicevt = *reinterpret_cast(pID3DDevice);
   ```
3. Nothing occurs when I try to rewrite the pointer to Direct3D
   device's `EndScene` function:

   ```
   // here '42' is EndScene's index inside the VMT, lol
   pID3DDevicevt[42] = my_EndScene;
   ```

   *Note:* I `VirtualProtect` that pointer before rewriting and
   `VirtualProtect` it back after, I just omitted that code.
4. I end up with 'classic' hooking: I rewrite 6 bytes of original
   function so it unconditionally jumps to my function. Then I restore
   original bytes, do my own stuff, call original function and rehook
   the function again. It works.

**Why does nothing occur when I try to rewrite the pointer to Direct3D device's `EndScene` function?**

I had searched and saw some info that the VMT hook has to be placed early enough in order to make it work. Is that the cause?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is probably very similar as the mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224747/win7-8-dwm-draw-hooking) but I use ID3D10Device1. It seems that Direct3D contains some kind of protection which periodically restores original vtable pointers for some methods.

I have not found the proper solution for this problem yet. The workaround is to execute background thread which periodically repatch the vtable. But it eats 100% CPU and does not catch all cases (due to race condition). Yield/Sleep can't be put into this thread because it would miss some function calls.

btw, what's that "'classic' hooking" ? I have already read something about it but I am not sure how to use it for x64 processes (adding jmp instruction, reading correct parameters, jumping back to original function etc...)

Comment: Hello, @bigmuscle! Much water has flown under the bridge since that, but maybe you have any ideas about this issues (or _the_ issue), do you? I would appreciate any information.

Comment: And what about that my "'classic' hooking" :-) I tried to describe what I mean in the question itself, please see my p.4. I am unable say anything about x64 environment, because, fortunately, I was limited by x86 case only.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to not do a vtable hook.  The best solution is to do what you're doing with the dummy device, grab the vtable, get the index for EndScene, de-reference it to get the address of the actual function and then perform a trampoline hook.

Full solution available in my other recent answer including the code for the trampoline hook [D3D9 Hooking (EndScene + DrawIndexedPrimitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652902/d3d9-hooking-endscene-drawindexedprimitive/61052959#61052959)