# D3D9 Hooking (EndScene + DrawIndexedPrimitive)

Tags: c++, hook, direct3d

As none of you already know, I am quite fed up with DirectX at the moment. I have tried and tried, and no matter what I do, I cannot seem to get any hooks to work. I have scoured the web and studied hooks; I have combined bits of code together to scrap together my own hook; I have flat out plagiarized hooks to find out how they worked; I have even written a few from scratch. However, I cannot seem to get one to work. I'm trying to make a simple D3D mod-menu for CrossFire. What I have tried:

1. Hooking via VTable [had issues with getting a device pointer]
2. Hooking via pattern + mask scanning, etc and detours [unsure how to get a pattern, and cannot find one that works reliably for win10]
3. Creating a dummy device to get the addresses, etc, etc [caused an immediate shut-down of the game (detected)]

No matter what I do, the menu either flat out refuses to appear once programmed into the detoured EndScene, I get shut-down, I crash, or nothing happens.

Are there any good starter materials with sample code that I can learn from, as well as get this off the ground?

I already have the hack menu programmed, the variables set, the features programmed, the DllMain, the dependencies, you name it. All I need is to get a proper hook working - the only one I got to work had a weird bug where text drawing in EndScene & wall-hack in DrawIndexedPrimitive didn't work.

Comment: http://www.directxtutorial.com/

Comment: I would just like to note that "hooking" has never been a supported usage scenario for any version of Direct3D. I know a lot of people have done it successfully, but it's always been quirky and brittle--the original PIX for Windows in the legacy DirectX SDK used detours and it was broken a lot by even the simplest updates to the operating system or apps. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you. I might also note that directXtutorial isn't really helpful from what I see, I know how to MAKE a directX app. I'm trying to hook one so I can disable the Z axis, do chams, etc.

Comment: I'm using minhook and creating dummy D3D/device in my hooks. So far it has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a large amount of code for a SO answer but here we go.

- Get correct window
- Create a dummy device
- Get address of endscene from vtable
- Do a standard x86 trampoline hook
- Inside hook do whatever initialize stuff you need to
- Get a copy of the correct device pointer
- Draw stuff
- call original function with correct device pointer

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

bool Hook(char* src, char* dst, int len)
{
    if (len < 5) return false;

    DWORD curProtection;

    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &curProtection);

    memset(src, 0x90, len);

    uintptr_t relativeAddress = (uintptr_t)(dst - src - 5);

    *src = (char)0xE9;
    *(uintptr_t*)(src + 1) = (uintptr_t)relativeAddress;

    DWORD temp;
    VirtualProtect(src, len, curProtection, &temp);

    return true;
}

char* TrampHook(char* src, char* dst, unsigned int len)
{
    if (len < 5) return 0;

    // Create the gateway (len + 5 for the overwritten bytes + the jmp)
    char* gateway = (char*)VirtualAlloc(0, len + 5, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    // Put the bytes that will be overwritten in the gateway
    memcpy(gateway, src, len);

    // Get the gateway to destination addy
    uintptr_t gateJmpAddy = (uintptr_t)(src - gateway - 5);

    // Add the jmp opcode to the end of the gateway
    *(gateway + len) = (char)0xE9;

    // Add the address to the jmp
    *(uintptr_t*)(gateway + len + 1) = gateJmpAddy;

    // Place the hook at the destination
    if (Hook(src, dst, len))
    {
        return gateway;
    }
    else return nullptr;
}


typedef HRESULT(APIENTRY* tEndScene)(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice);

static HWND window;


BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback(HWND handle, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD wndProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &wndProcId);

    if (GetCurrentProcessId() != wndProcId)
        return TRUE; // skip to next window

    window = handle;
    return FALSE; // window found abort search
}

HWND GetProcessWindow()
{
    window = NULL;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, NULL);
    return window;
}

bool GetD3D9Device(void** pTable, size_t Size)
{
    if (!pTable)
        return false;

    IDirect3D9* pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (!pD3D)
        return false;

    IDirect3DDevice9* pDummyDevice = NULL;

    // options to create dummy device
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp = {};
    d3dpp.Windowed = false;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = GetProcessWindow();

    HRESULT dummyDeviceCreated = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &pDummyDevice);

    if (dummyDeviceCreated != S_OK)
    {
        // may fail in windowed fullscreen mode, trying again with windowed mode
        d3dpp.Windowed = !d3dpp.Windowed;

        dummyDeviceCreated = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &pDummyDevice);

        if (dummyDeviceCreated != S_OK)
        {
            pD3D->Release();
            return false;
        }
    }

    memcpy(pTable, *reinterpret_cast<void***>(pDummyDevice), Size);

    pDummyDevice->Release();
    pD3D->Release();
    return true;
}

void DrawFilledRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9* dev)
{
    D3DRECT BarRect = { x, y, x + w, y + h };
    dev->Clear(1, &BarRect, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_TARGET, color, 0, 0);
}


bool bInit = false;
tEndScene oEndScene = nullptr;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pD3DDevice = nullptr;
void* d3d9Device[119];

HRESULT APIENTRY hkEndScene(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    if (bInit == false)
    {
        pD3DDevice = pDevice;
        bInit = true;
    }

    //draw stuff here like so:
    DrawFilledRect(200, 200, 200, 200, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 0, 0), pDevice);

    return oEndScene(pDevice);
}

DWORD WINAPI Init(HMODULE hModule)
{
    if (GetD3D9Device(d3d9Device, sizeof(d3d9Device)))
    {
        oEndScene = (tEndScene)TrampHook((char*)d3d9Device[42], (char*)hkEndScene, 7);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Init, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Credits to me, Broihon, Solaire & 0xDEC0DE for this barebones d3d9 endscene hook